# Property 'sourceInformation' not found on object of type 'CLLocation

Tags: javascript

Property 'sourceInformation' not found on object of type 'CLLocation when i install Geolocation library in IOS

When attempting to retrieve the current location after installing the GeoLibrary library, I encounter the error "Property 'sourceInformation' not found on object of type 'CLLocation." If I install a version that is two years old, then I encounter the error "react/config/ReactNativeConfig.h' file not found."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.